# Passing dictionary to view and showing the view in series will not render

Tags: swift, swiftui

**NOTE: I am not sure the best way to word the title, so if you can help change it feel free.**

I have an array of dictionary in which I would like to pass the dictionaries of the array to a second view depending on the current index. Problem is when I change the index the view never renders the values of the dictionary at that index.

Using a normal `ForEach` loop works fine, but if I step through the array using an index (in the original application we are using `LinkedList`) the problem occurs

Here is the reproducible code, it will make much more sense.

Just copy and paste

```
//
//  Test2.swift
//  SwiftUIPlayground
//
//  Created by Muhand Jumah on 10/18/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Test2: View {
    @State private var args: [[String:Any]] = []
    
    @State private var currentIndex: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Previous") {
                    self.movePrevious()
                }
                
                Button("Next") {
                    self.moveNext()
                }
            }
            
            if self.currentIndex != nil {
                Text("Current Index: \(self.currentIndex!)")

                EntityAView(args: self.args[currentIndex!])
            } else {
                Text("No entity to show")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.getEntities()
            
            if self.args.count > 0 {
                self.currentIndex = 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func moveNext() {
        guard args.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        
        guard currentIndex != nil else {
            currentIndex = 0
            return
        }
        
        if self.currentIndex! + 1 < self.args.count {
            self.currentIndex! += 1
        } else {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
    }
    
    private func movePrevious() {
        guard args.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        
        guard currentIndex != nil else {
            currentIndex = 0
            return
        }
        
        if self.currentIndex! - 1 >= 0 {
            self.currentIndex! -= 1
        } else {
            currentIndex = self.args.count - 1
        }
    }
    
    private func getEntities() {
        self.args.append(["name": "Muhand"])
        self.args.append(["name": "Jumah"])
        self.args.append(["name": "John"])
    }
}

struct EntityAView: View {
    @State private(set) var args: [String: Any]
    @State private var name: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if name == nil {
                Text("LOADING....")
            } else {
                Text(self.name!)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            guard
                let raw = self.args["name"],
                let _name = raw as? String
            else {
                return
            }
            
            self.name = _name
        }
    }
}

struct Test2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test2()
    }
}
```

What is expected from the above code, is when pressing `Next` it should show the next data, for example: it starts at index `0` showing the data `Muhand` on pressing `Next` it should show "Jumah" but that is not the case here. If I change dictionary to `String` then it works just fine.

It is important I keep the dictionary and stepping this way because most of the data will be retrieved from an API. So each view must compute its appropriate arguments from the dictionary.

Comment: `private(set) var args` why? then use `private let args`

Comment: In the original example in which this was abstracted from I change args inside that particular object and I don't want to change it out side but I would like it to be read. Hence the `private(set)`and net `let`

Comment: If you want JUST read then use `let` also I forgot to tell you you cannot use private before `let` because you want get data to work

Comment: Other objects can not change it, they can only read. But the object itself can update the variable. If it is `let` then it is read only everywhere. Either way, that is not the problem here.

Comment: Then you have to use State wrapper for sure as private

Comment: You are right, I missed the state wrapper. Although it didn’t solve the problem but good catch.

Comment: I think you are facing with easy issue that can get solved, but the example of issue is too much to read and a little mass, if you could just make very simple and less code example it could help more to get your issue solved. And just focus on one issue, not multi issues.

Comment: I think it is easy as well; However, I tried to condense it as much as I can. In the above code there is only 1 issue not multiple. I suppose what we can change is remove 1 of the views. The reason I say I condensed it as much as I can is because this issue only occurs when you step through the views. For example, if you use a normal `ForEach` loop it works just fine; But, stepping through the views is a core feature of the app hence I had to include it in the above example. Other than the stepping I haven't added anything extra.

Comment: With that being said I will try to condense it a bit more and update

Comment: @swiftPunk I have updated the question. I hope it's easier now.

Comment: You do realize that the only time you set `name` in `EntityAView` is in the `.onAppear`. So it gets set to the original name, and is never updated. This is a product of the extremely complex model you have here. It took a lot of reviewing this code to realize this. There are many, much simpler ways of cycling through views than this.